# check box on custom listview

Tags: android, radio-button

[image] me getting like this it should not only show on particular item
How to make radio buttons in custom listview as single mode. If I click on particular radio button then it has to appear and the other one as unselected. If click on 1st row then radio button on first row selected.click on second row radion button on second row seleceted and first row unselected.click on third row radio button on third row selected and first row and second row unselected.

**customlist.xml**

> ```
> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:orientation="vertical" >
>
> <RadioButton
>       android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
>       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>       android:text=""
>
>        />
>
>   <TextView
>       android:id="@+id/card"
>       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>       android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton1"
>       android:text=""
>       android:textColor="#000000"
>       android:textSize="15dip"
>       android:textStyle="bold" />
>
>
>   </RelativeLayout>
>
>   listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cardlist);
>
> adapter =new MyAdapter(this, app.arryList,app.arryList1);
>
> listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
>
>   @Override
>   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
>       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
>       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "am thelist",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>
>
>   }
> });
>
>
> listView.setAdapter(adapter);
>
> listView.setChoiceMode(listView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
> }
>
>
>
> public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
>
> Context context = null;
> ArrayList<String> items= null;
> ArrayList<String> items1= null;
>
>
> public MyAdapter(Newcard newcard, ArrayList<String> items,
>       ArrayList<String> items1) {
>   // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
>
>   this.items = items;
>   this.items1 = items1;
>
> }
>
> @Override
> public int getCount() {
>   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>   return items.size();
> }
>
> @Override
> public Object getItem(int position) {
>   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>   return items; 
>
>   //return items.get(position);
> }
>
> @Override
> public long getItemId(int position) {
>   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>   return position;
> }
>
> @Override
> public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
>   View layout = null;
>   TextView produ = null;  
>
>   TextView desc = null;
>   Button edit = null;
>
>   RadioButton radio =null;
>
>   if (convertView == null) {
>
>       lay = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
>       layout = lay.inflate(R.layout.customlist, null);
>   } else {
>       layout = convertView;
>   }
>
>   produ = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.card);
>   produ.setText("" +app.arryList.get(position));
>
>
>   radio = (RadioButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
>
>
>
>   radio.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
>
>       @Override
>       public void onClick(View v) {
>           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
>                       //check.setVisibility(View.GONE);
>
>
>           System.out.println("data "+app.arryList.get(position)); 
>
>       }
>   });
>
>
>
>       }
>   });
>
>
>
>   return layout;
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to solve your issue and done from my side.

I explain approach below and for more details and complete Source code go through this blog below.

http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-custon-single-choice-lsitview.html

Hope this will solve your problem.

[image]

I created Custom single Choice list. You can change the layout and add your widget accordingly.

Step1)

```
package com.custom.view;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Checkable;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class CheckableRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout implements
        Checkable {

    private boolean isChecked;
    private List<Checkable> checkableViews;

    public CheckableRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initialise(attrs);
    }

    public CheckableRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialise(attrs);
    }

    public CheckableRelativeLayout(Context context, int checkableId) {
        super(context);
        initialise(null);
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return isChecked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean isChecked) {
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
        for (Checkable c : checkableViews) {
            c.setChecked(isChecked);
        }
    }
    public void toggle() {
        this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
        for (Checkable c : checkableViews) {
            c.toggle();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        final int childCount = this.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
            findCheckableChildren(this.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Read the custom XML attributes
     */
    private void initialise(AttributeSet attrs) {
        this.isChecked = false;
        this.checkableViews = new ArrayList<Checkable>(5);
    }

    /**
     * Add to our checkable list all the children of the view that implement the
     * interface Checkable
     */
    private void findCheckableChildren(View v) {
        if (v instanceof Checkable) {
            this.checkableViews.add((Checkable) v);
        }

        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            final ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            final int childCount = vg.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
                findCheckableChildren(vg.getChildAt(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Step2)

```
package com.custom.view;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
public class InertCheckBox extends CheckBox {

    public InertCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public InertCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public InertCheckBox(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyMultiple(int keyCode, int repeatCount, KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyShortcut(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTrackballEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Step3)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.custom.view.CheckableRelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">


    <com.custom.view.InertCheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/singleitemCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
        android:focusable="false" 
        android:button="@drawable/single_radio_chice" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/singleitemId" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/singleitemCheckBox"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textSize="14sp" 
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nextitem" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/singleitemId"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textSize="14sp" 
        android:focusable="false" />

</com.custom.view.CheckableRelativeLayout>


Step4)

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:listSelector="#00000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Step5) single_radio_chice.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item android:state_checked="false" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/radio_off" />

        <item android:state_checked="true" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/radio_on" />
    </selector>
```

Comment: how can we make of the radiobutton checked by default initially?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Use `ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE`

```
 listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` will be more suitable for his needs.

But maybe it will be a not bad idea to save an array of your radio buttons and to set them accordingly.

Comment: i checked with ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE and istView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE); both are not working